# CGI Generic Injectable Parameter

Tags: nessus

In this security scan, the parameter is found to be at risk of cross-site scripting attacks. Does this mean as below under name="target" attackers can replace the value of 'target' ? What sort of risk would there be ?

```
Using the GET HTTP method, Nessus found that :
+ The following resources may be vulnerable to injectable parameter :
+ The 'target' parameter of the /phpMyAdmin/index.php CGI :
/phpMyAdmin/index.php?target=%00aqumwy
-------- output --------
</div>    <input type="hidden" name="server" value="1" /></fieldset>
<fieldset class="tblFooters">
<input value="Go" type="submit" id="input_go" /><input type="hidden" nam
e="target" value=".aqumwy" /><input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en"
 /><input type="hidden" name="collation_connection" value="utf8_unicode_
ci" /><input type="hidden" name="token" value="a0bf0035955980a4e6546e545
5aab1f6" /></fieldset>
</form></div></div></body></html>
------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - **yes** but it does not actually matter.

PHPMyAdmin has the `target` variable so it can redirect you to a specific page in the console after login.

So for example:
You are a logged in user and you left a tab open at `xxx.php` and after X amount of time the system logged you out and now when you log back in you want to get to the same page you were on (`xxx.php`) so the url will look something like `index.php?target=xxx.php`.

Where are the threats?

- XSS - If you are able to escape the value of `target` in the `value="XSS_HERE"`
- Redirecting a user to a dangerous location/website (`export.php`, `import.php`, `site_with_virus.com`)

How does PHPMyAdmin protect from these this?

- XSS - They filter out anything that is not on their white list as well as sanitizing the parameter.
- Dangerous redirects - There is a blacklist array as well as a whitelist array with all the locations that can be redirected and all the locations that cannot be redirected.

In Conclusion:

Yes you can inject code into the `value` but it is useless as it is sanitized and verified on login.

My answer is taken mostly from looking over PHPMyAdmin code on [Github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin).